# How to fix the nz-table remove the no data display in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```
<nz-table #listTable nzSize="middle" [nzData]="data">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th nzShowExpand></th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Device</th>
          <th class="tbWidth text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <ng-template ngFor let-data [ngForOf]="listTable.data">
          <tr>
            <td nzShowExpand [(nzExpand)]="mapOfExpandData[data.id]"></td>
            <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.name"></td>
            <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.device"></td>
            <td nzBreakWord class="text-center">
              <nz-button-group>
                <button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="openFormDrawer(data)"><i nz-icon nzType="edit"
                    nzTheme="outline"></i></button>
                <button nz-button nzType="danger" (click)="deleteRoomData(data)"><i nz-icon nzType="delete"
                    nzTheme="outline"></i></button>
              </nz-button-group>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr [nzExpand]="mapOfExpandData[data.id]">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan=7>
              <nz-table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th nzWidth="25%">Location Code</th>
                    <th nzWidth="25%">Location Description</th>
                    <th nzWidth="25%">Device Code</th>
                    <th nzWidth="25%">Device Description</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.locationCode"></td>
                    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.locationDescription"></td>
                    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.deviceCode"></td>
                    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.deviceDescription"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </nz-table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-template>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```

Why the "NO DATA" keep showing?
[image]

How to remove the no data display in ng zorro?
cause there's a data but the "NO DATA" is always displaying, How to remove the "NO DATA" in angular zorro?

the expand is working, but when it click the expand the "NO DATA" also display, but there's a data inside the nz-table.

if there's a data it shouldn't display, if there's no data it will display. but even there's a data it also display.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add `[nzData]="['']"` to your subtable

This messag is visible when `nzData` is empty in `nz-table`

```
<nz-table [nzData]="['']">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th nzWidth="25%">Location Code</th>
    <th nzWidth="25%">Location Description</th>
    <th nzWidth="25%">Device Code</th>
    <th nzWidth="25%">Device Description</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.locationCode"></td>
    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.locationDescription"></td>
    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.deviceCode"></td>
    <td nzBreakWord [textContent]="data.deviceDescription"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

Comment: you solution doesn't apply in case of table with client side pagination.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `nzTemplateMode` to your nz-table

```
<nz-table nzTemplateMode>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nz-table [nzData]="products" [nzFrontPagination]="false" [nzShowPagination]="false" [nzNoResult]="toto">
.....
</nz-table>

<ng-template #toto class="tt">
 <span *ngIf="products.length === 0">Aucun produit en promo</span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).